# When does a SUICIDE opcode becomes effective?

Tags: contract-development, opcode, selfdestruct

The documentation (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Subtleties) states that SUICIDE becomes effective at the end of the transaction, but in block 116525, the same contract was able to SUICIDE three times in three distinct transactions:

```
0x7476afface26678a6c236618a7079db7ce567a213dc75652378f3580e1a10f28
0x51826f28e829cb9425dbd1c77a2c77484d04d8b02ccab05934e5885d313fbe91
0xa6c23583bba9139ca7e168328a2d15978d90dfdd61a6be697abbec1846b59e01
```

is it a bug that has since been fixed, or is a SUICIDE only effective after a block is complete?

Comment: why do you say suicide has been called 3 times ? I see it only happening in the 1st you mention but can be wrong of course

Comment: ethercamp explorer and debug_traceTransaction report it for all 3 transactions (could be a bug in both of these though)

Comment: I only see it showing up once on [ethercamp](https://live.ether.camp/account/4d95fbaf35fc5a815983f9df94821c1c089dc02f).

Comment: What version of geth are you using? I get the bug on 1.5.0, do you see it on 1.4.3?

Comment: I am on 1.5.0 from ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev, I cannot see it in ethercamp anymore, must have gotten confused at some point :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A SUICIDE operation is effective at the end of the transaction. I can replicate the issue, so it likely is a bug in the geth `traceTransaction` implementation, where the other prior transactions in the block are not taken into account.

**Edit:** this bug has been [fixed](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/f7fdfa4eace4f0ab1dd820398efa0f2f44bd1eca)

Comment: I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2542) feel free to chime in with your geth version, etc.

Comment: Added a comment in [issue #2542](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2542), and, yes, that is with 1.5.0